# Please don't argue with people over their answer

Tags: discussion

Just had a guy with like 9k rep argue with me over how I picked the poorer answer (i.e. not his). I picked the answer I did for multiple reasons, including the fact that it literally answered my question in his first sentence.

Please don't do this to people. It's annoying and does not make anyone 'want' to come around to your way of thinking. If you want to respectfully ask why they picked the answer they did and point out the merits of another answer then by all means do so. But for crying out loud leave it at that... they can change it if they want and trying to judge them and tell them they picked the wrong answer isn't going to accomplish anything (except perhaps the opposite of what you want).

Comment: I agree that comments like that generally aren't constructive. But are you asking a question?

Comment: Nope... I just know the type of people who would do this are the type of people who would use meta and see this here. Feel free to close or whatever if this isn't an appropriate place to share my thoughts on the matter.

Comment: You could edit it so that it is a question. Incidentally, the person who posted those comments has virtually no record of participating in Meta.

Comment: Lol, oh well. Nah that's okay. Guess I just wanted to vent. I feel better now. :)

Comment: Finally someone agrees and advocates that we *never* should comment on negative actions - "downvote and move on" is better course of action in such case. (comment seriousness level 3.7)

Comment: Human beings, how do they interact?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you see such a comment, be it from 50 rep user or 1000000 rep user, you can simply ignore the comment.

Do not reply to the comment.

If you want, flag it as "not constructive", because that's exactly what it is. If it contains the word "accept" it might even  get insta-deleted by the flag.

By engaging the other user and starting an argument, you're just upsetting yourself for no need.

Comment: Sage advice. One of these days I will learn to do that. :)

Comment: Yeah... I must admit, many times I don't take my own advice and engage in useless arguments. :/

Comment: @ShadowWizard you know why, there is always that glimmer of hope that you get a message across and have to try. Congratulations, you're human ;)