# An accepted answer has a very low score, an other answer is far better and has more score but is not accepted

Tags: discussion

[Python: Find a substring in a string and returning the index of the substring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21842885/python-find-a-substring-in-a-string-and-returning-the-index-of-the-substring/21842990#21842990)

Especially at this post, the accepted answer has only a score of "2" while a far better answer has a score of 62, which should be the correct answer. However the user does not seem to respond, is inactive or whatever. Is there the possbility to change the accepted answer?

Comment: The accepted answer is the answer which worked best for the question's author at the time, it is not the accepted answer that we all live by. There is no need for anyone else to change it. You are probably bothered by the fact that the accepted answer sticks to the top - search meta to see you are not alone.

Comment: this has been asked before for sure, but the OP can accept any answer they want. i'll find the dupe...

Comment: This is recent example from OP point of view when someone suggested that there is a better answer than accepted one -  http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/342788/please-dont-argue-with-people-over-their-answer

Answer (score 8):

No you cannot change the accepted answer.  What you need to remember is that accept does not mean this is "the answer".  What it does mean is it is the answer helped the OP the most.

One thing we could do is not stick the accepted answer to the top of the answer section.  If you are sorting by votes then only votes should count and the accepted answer should sit wherever its votes would put it if it was not accepted.

Comment: I like that idea, it should be a feature

Comment: @Developer I'm pretty sure there is a feature request for this already

Comment: SO should get on top of that then

Comment: [status-declined], though: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326095/please-unpin-the-accepted-answer-from-the-top

Answer (score 4):

The user said he can't use the function described in the answer with 62 votes. Plus it's up to the OP to chose what they want. Usually people scroll past the answer and read others as well.